# Button to select all check boxes and change entire table's bg color

Tags: jquery, button

this is what i have so far:
- a table with 20 to 30 cells
- each cell has 1 check box and a value (different value of course)
- two button to trigger select all and select none checkboxes.

Codes so far:
- to trigger select all/none:

Javascript:

```
function set_checked(checked) {
    $('input[name=test]').attr('checked', checked);
}
```

buttons:

```
onclick="set_checked(true)" and onclick="set_checked(false)" for both buttons.
```

now, how do i add color change on both buttons? for example, entire table bg color change to green when select all and change to white when select none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do, what is needed

```
function set_checked(checked) {
    $('input:checked').attr('checked', checked); //select all checkbox
    if(checked) {
         $("table").css("backgroundColor", "#ddd"); //new color
    } else {
         $("table").css("backgroundColor", "#fff"); //old color
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, and i come up with this demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/unicorn/tbL9j/  what i have to do so the color change only appears on the checkbox cell but not covering the entire table?

Comment: i did it! weeeeeeeee, give an id to td, and replace the "table" to the id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.css` to change background color:

```
$("tableSelector").css("background-color","blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
onclick="set_checked(true); $('table').css('background', 'green')"
onclick="set_checked(false); $('table').css('background', 'white')"
```